# How can I ask the "distance between my position and the position that's required''?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

I went to a job interview and when I was interviewed he told me that I wasn't qualified yet.

I wanted to ask the distance between my position and the position that's required for the job.

How could I ask

- how much time should I spend to reach that point?
- how far am I to reach your requirement?
- ...

I think they're not correct. How can I ask this kind of questions?

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew has pointed out, it might be better to ask more specific questions about the difference in skills or experience level between what you have and what they want.

If you really do want to use the analogy of distance, you can say

> How far away am I from what you require?

or

> How far do I fall short of what you require?

or

> By how much do I fall short of what you require?

Answer (score 2):

> "What would I need to do / achieve to be qualified for this job?
>
> "What additional skills would be required for me to get this job?
>
> "What is missing from my skill set or work history that I would need to acquire to be able to do this job?"

And various others.  In English I don't think we would see "distance" as the right metaphor for this situation.  It's more like a "tool belt" that's missing tools.